# What's the proper way to bind a QImage to a texture to display video in QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to implement an efficient video player, So I started from the Qt's textures example.

**I have:**

```
void HUD::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    makeObject();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

#define PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE 0
#define PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE 1

    QOpenGLShader *vshader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, this);
    const char *vsrc =
        "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
        "attribute mediump vec4 texCoord;\n"
        "varying mediump vec4 texc;\n"
        "uniform mediump mat4 matrix;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = matrix * vertex;\n"
        "    texc = texCoord;\n"
        "}\n";
    vshader->compileSourceCode(vsrc);

    QOpenGLShader *fshader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, this);
    const char *fsrc =
        "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
        "varying mediump vec4 texc;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texc.st);\n"
        "}\n";
    fshader->compileSourceCode(fsrc);

    program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram;
    program->addShader(vshader);
    program->addShader(fshader);
    program->bindAttributeLocation("vertex", PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE);
    program->bindAttributeLocation("texCoord", PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE);
    program->link();

    program->bind();
    program->setUniformValue("texture", 0);
}

void HUD::paintGL()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    glClearColor(clearColor.redF(), clearColor.greenF(), clearColor.blueF(), clearColor.alphaF());
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    static int ctt = 0;
    QMatrix4x4 m;
    m.ortho(-0.2f, +0.2f, +0.2f, -0.2f, 4.0f, 15.0f);
    m.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    program->setUniformValue("matrix", m);
    program->enableAttributeArray(PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE);
    program->enableAttributeArray(PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE);
    program->setAttributeBuffer(PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat));
    program->setAttributeBuffer(PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE, GL_FLOAT, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 2, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat));

    //???//
    //How to bind the QImage into a texture efficiently???
    //???//
    textures->bind();// textures is a QOpenGLTexture
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0 * 4, 4);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    qDebug() << elapsed_secs;

}
```

The example originally used the **QOpenGLTexture** to read from one single QImage and bind it to the quad painted by paintGL() function.

However, How could I update the content of the texture so I could display a video at 30 Hz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at Qt [video widget example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-videowidget-example.html) which is a basic video player. You can also stream video to a [QGraphicsVideoItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsvideoitem.html) you can display in a QGraphicsView, which can contain other graphics items and can render OpenGL content if you provide it with a QOpenGLWidget viewport.
If you want to roll your own you might want to use the Qt video functionalities and implement a class based on [QAbstractVideoSurface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html) to receive video frames from the media player. Take a look at the handleType() of the QVideoFrame. If it is QAbstractVideoBuffer::GLTextureHandle or QAbstractVideoBuffer::EGLImageHandle you might be able to just draw it to screen using a quad shader with its handle() as a texture id. If not write the data to a QOpenGLTexture. You can upload textures in a thread to prevent blocking the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that QOpenGLTexture class does not allow to update the image data, see [QOpenGLTexture::allocateStorage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html#allocateStorage).

In this case you should consider allocating your own OpenGL texture and updating it. This can be done with the following code:

```
// Keep the ID somewhere
GLuint textureId;
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

// First frame
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, <w>, <h>, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame.bits());

// Subsequent frames
glTextSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, <w>, <h>, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame.bits());

// Destruction
glDeleteTextures(1, &textureId);
```

And for preparing your pixel data before uploading you can do something like this:

```
QImage prepareFrame(const QImage& frame) {
    if(frame.format() != QImage::Format_RGB888) {
        return frame.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
    }
    return frame;
}
```

Comment: The immutable texture storage Qt uses (if available at all) does _not_ imply that the texture data is immutable. Just the texture properties (size, internal format, number of mip map levels) are fixed. The image data can be updated any time by using `glSubTexImage()` or by rendering into it.

Comment: Correct, I have made a little confusion, moreover it seems that there is not even the need to use a native OpenGL function to update the data, OpenGLTexture::setData() can be called more than once. Well, I like handmade things :)

Comment: Is it a typo, under `Subsequent frames`, shall `glTextSubImage2D` be `glTexSubImage2D`?

Comment: on a performance point of view, uploading 24bit data is less efficient than uploading 32bit, and using RGBA is less efficient then BGRA. See this post for a detailed explanation : https://community.khronos.org/t/updating-textures-per-frame/75020/3